# Offline Map Application Development Android

Tags: android, dictionary, offline

I have a project , android application with offline Map. user should download map once, or It should come with the app and then without internet be able to make marks and so on.

Can you give me Idea, which maps should I use, and little example . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [osmdroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

osmdroid is a (almost) full/free replacement for Android's `MapView` class. It also includes a modular tile provider system with support for numerous **online** and **offline** tile sources and overlay support with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location, and drawing shapes.

Also see [osmbonuspack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/)